# Listening program cannot be started after being left for a period of time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

About a month ago, I used Winforms to write a simple listening and reading program to assist in the completion of work. But recently something strange happened.

When I re-open this project with Visual Studio 2022, the following error occurs

`The ‘DiagnosticsHubPackage’ package did not correctly.The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\...\VisualStudio\17.0_e476ad3d\ActivityLog.xml'.`

I checked a lot of information but I don't seem to have any ideas. Some people say that Windows or VS needs to be updated. But that's obviously nonsense, because I've had it work fine before.
And, after I clicked Yes on the wrong prompt box, I successfully entered VS and opened the project.

However, when I run the project, it is displayed at an automatically generated code

`System.ArgumentException: 'Source object does not expose 'IPropertyNotifySink' event interface.'` 
Code:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel2.ResumeLayout(false);
this.tableLayoutPanel2.PerformLayout();
((System. ComponentModel. ISupportInitialize)(this. pictureBox1)). EndInit();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1)).EndInit(); //error
this. ResumeLayout(false);
```

Does anyone have the same experience, let's discuss how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure _"The 'DiagnosticsHubPackage' package did not correctly."_ is the entire message? It's odd because it's clearly incomplete and unlike any message I've seen from the compiler.

Comment: A web search on `"DiagnosticsHubPackage"` produces [amongst others]: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4ffb9447-55c3-49ed-b541-d606801b2e53/unable-to-load-diagnosticshubpackage-vs2015?forum=vssetup

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I added a more complete error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first exception, you can try the method in the link provided by Craig Estey. And you said that you have successfully opened it, so will this error still appear when you reopen the solution later?

For your second exception, it should be that you have made some changes to the exception settings while using Visual Studio. You try the following steps:

**Debug**>**Windows**>**Exception Settings**>**Restore the list to the default settings**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I found this workaround too. But I didn't find where to restore the list to the default settings. thank you for your help